# making a function to retrieve information from a key in a dictionary

Tags: python

I am a newbie programmer so sorry if any of these are dumb questions.  This class is my first ever programming experience.

I am trying to create a search function that will search a dictionary and upon invoking it would give you all the keys from the dictionary separated by a '/t'.  I then want to make the function prompt the user to enter a key.  When the key is in the dictionary the key is supposed to give you the the information from the dictionary.  When the key is not in the dictionary I want to create an output message such as "That student is not in class".

I have created a function off of my dictionary which will simply print all the information from the dict if you enter the correct key; however it is not off of the search function.  I know I am lacking in having a true/except block that works, and a while true and return function.
 I need to make (searchStudentDict) or use a true/except block or while true or a return statement.  Below is my incorrect code trying to do this problem within it's boundaries.

```
def searchStudentDict():  
    for i in dctStudents.keys():  
         try:  
              while true:  
         except:  
              print('That student is not in class')  
     return  

searchStudentDict(dctStudents)
```

I would be forever grateful to anyone who could edit this and get this to actually show up in the code block I've spent more time formatting than on my question.  It isn't taking any of the indents i made

The expected output is the keys below tab separated such as

```
7373'\t'8274'\t'9651'\t'2213'\t'8787'\t'9999
```

*using python create tab here since the physical tab key will not tab them apart.

```
dctStudents = {
'7373':['Walter White',52,'Teacher'],
'8274':['Skyler White',49,'Author'],
'9651':['Jesse Pinkman',27,'Student'],
'2213':['Saul Goodman',43,'Lawyer'],
'6666':['Gus Fring',54,'Chicken Guy'],
'8787':['Kim Wexler',36,'Lawyer'],
'9999':['Tuco Salamanca',53,'Drug Lord'] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*` unpacking with `sep` argument of `print`:

```
print(*dctStudents, sep='\t')
```

When inside a function, this looks like:

```
def searchStudentDict(): 
    print(*dctStudents, sep='\t')
```

...will print keys of the dictionary separated by tab space.

You can do following to retrieve value of a key if its present or throw a message if it's not present:

```
def searchStudentDict(): 
    print(dctStudents.get(input('Enter key: '), 'That student is not in class'))
```

Comment: @passRushingProgrammer, you don't need a `try`. Just this line inside the function. I will update.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will display all of the keys from the dictionary separated by tabs

```py
print('\t'.join(someDict.keys()))
```

If you want to search the dictionary for a specific key and print out the value that corresponds to that key while guarding against exceptions, the basic example is one way of doing so:

```py
def searchStudentDict(someDict):  
    targetKey = ""

    # End at user's request
    while True:
        targetKey = input("Enter a student ID (\'q\' to quit): ")

        if targetKey.lower() == 'q':
            break

        # Search for it in dictionary using try-except (handle exceptions)
        try:
            print("Student {} Info: {}".format(targetKey, someDict[targetKey]))
        except KeyError:
            print("No information exists for this student")
        except:
            print("Some unknown error occurred")
            # Handle how you see fit

    print('Ending search...')

def main():
    studentDict = {
        '7373' : ['Walter White',52,'Teacher'],
        '8274' : ['Skyler White',49,'Author'],
        '9651' : ['Jesse Pinkman',27,'Student'],
        '2213' : ['Saul Goodman',43,'Lawyer'],
        '6666' : ['Gus Fring',54,'Chicken Guy'],
        '8787' : ['Kim Wexler',36,'Lawyer'],
        '9999' : ['Tuco Salamanca',53,'Drug Lord'] 
    }

    # Print the existing students
    print('\t'.join(studentDict.keys()))

    # Perform search
    searchStudentDict(studentDict)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the corresponding output would be:

```
$ py -3 search.py
7373    8274    9651    2213    6666    8787    9999
Enter a student ID ('q' to quit): 8274
Student 8274 Info: ['Skyler White', 49, 'Author']
Enter a student ID ('q' to quit): 9999
Student 9999 Info: ['Tuco Salamanca', 53, 'Drug Lord']
Enter a student ID ('q' to quit): 1111
No information exists for this student
Enter a student ID ('q' to quit): q
Ending search...
```

Typically, you would not want to handle a search inside a dictionary this way (using `try-except`). A simple `if` statement or the use of `get` should suffice but if you require the use of a try-except, you would need to guard against the `KeyError` that would be raised if you try to access a key that does not exist. Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't need an `if` statement; this is what the `get` method is for. `print(someDict.get(targetKey, "No data exists for this key"))`.

Comment: Can you make an edit to my work?  Feel free to if so, I believe that you are on the track to the answer I need.  I need to have The part where you ask the user to enter a key and where you retrieve the value for that key should be placed inside a try block.  Inside your except block, your program should output a message such as: That student is not in the class.

Comment: @passRushingProgrammer, you can use `try`-`except`, but dictionary `get` function helps to output error message if the key is not found (as said by chepner).

Comment: I believe this may pertain to an problem he is completing for his "first ever programming experience" which might be practicing the use of a `try-except`, although this is an odd example for that, I believe that is why he requested it.

Comment: Thanks Adrian yes this is for an intro level programming class for a career change,

Comment: Hey I did not get an output from that.  I didn't get any errors running the script but I didn't get any output on the screen.

Comment: I have updated the post to include an entire script that you can copy and paste to view the sample output. I also added what I believe to be your requested behavior of using a looping structure to continue querying your dictionary of students.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution that may work for you:

```
#First print all the keys separated by tabs
print('\t'.join(someDict.keys()))
#Infinite loop
while True:
  #read user input
  userinput = input("Enter a key: ")
  #the method get will try to get the key, if no matches will display the string passed.
  print(someDict.get(userinput, "No key matches the dict"))
```

Comment: thank you, I will probably comment on this further when I get back from work!  This is what I'm looking for I think!  Thanks!!!

Comment: You are welcome, hope that it helps solving your problem!